# Including picture cause previous page text to have extra space in between sentences

Tags: includegraphics, vertical-spacing

I'm taking database management system class notes on latex.
I wrote notes that filled half page, and then included a picture with scale = 1, that didn't fit on the same page, and was moved to the next page (which is ok), the text on that page (that initially filled half of it) now covers the entire page, with a lot of vertical space between the sentences.
Below screenshots of the problem and the latex code.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the vertical spacing problem]
[image: Here is the screenshot of the inserted image]
here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, notitlepage]{book}

\usepackage[
            top = 1in,
            bottom = 1in,
            left = 0.75in,
            right = 0.75in
            ]{geometry}
        
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Query Language}
Provides operations on data, and possibly some advanced functions.

\subsection{Relational Model}
Easy
\section{Why Use DBMS}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{itemize}
\item Applications with tight real-time constraints.
\item Application with a few well-defined critical operations for which efficient custom code must be written.
\item Application may need to manipulate the data in ways not supported by the query language.
\end{itemize}
\section{General Overview: Query Processing}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{dbms_overview}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are using flushbottom so tex has to make the last line go to the bottom of the page. This is exactly why images are normally placed in a `figure` environment allowing latex to move it to get better page breaks. Or add `\raggedbottom` to your preamble.

Comment: That is a consequence of using `center` + image, if it does not fit, it leaves a gap on the proceeding page and deping on your class (of which you give no information) that page may stretch. You should look into using the `figure` (float) environment for your figures, this also have support for captions.

Comment: Note you should show code as a complete small document not a fragment or an image. The relevant code here (selecting `\flushbottom`) is not shown (usually that is the default in book classes and not the default in "article" classes, but you have not shown your document class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, sorry, the document class is "book", I edited the code to show all the preamble, I tried the enclosing it in figure environment, it did solve the spacing problem, however I'm not satisfied with the result, is there a way to set the picture's height to whatever is left from the page? with optionally a minimum height that beyond it the figure breaks into a new page?

Comment: I also tried the \raggedbottom in the preamble and it was with a neater output